# Save As DialogueBox is not working in servlet response.setHeader

Tags: java, jquery, excel, servlets, dialog

I am exporting data displayed in jqgrid into .excel file by clicking button .
Here is my code for export to excel button click..

```
 $('#excel').click(function(){
            var fromdate=$('#fromdate').val();
            var todate=$('#todate').val();
            if(fromdate && todate)
            {
                var URL='excel?fromdate='+$('#fromdate').val()+'&todate='+$('#todate').val();
                $.ajax({
                   url:URL,
                   type:'GET',
                   success:function(data){
                       alert('Exported To Excel');
                   }

                });
            }
        });
```

Now this button will direct to excel.java  page  which is servlet.Below is my exceljava page code .Now Asper my need when the user click on export to excel button a openwith and save as dialogue box should popup which gives user ability to give desired name and save to desired positionbut it is not happening with this code.plz point out my mistake ..

excel.java

```
  try {

    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=excel.xls");

    String datum1 = request.getParameter("fromdate");
    String datum2 = request.getParameter("todate");
    SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date = sdfSource.parse(datum1);
    Date date2 = sdfSource.parse(datum2);
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    datum1 = sdfDestination.format(date);
    System.out.println(datum1);
    datum2 = sdfDestination.format(date2);
    System.out.println(datum2);


    HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("CallBillingSystem");

    HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
    rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("calldate");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("src");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("dst");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("dstchannel");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue("lastapp");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue("duration");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 6).setCellValue("disposition");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 7).setCellValue("amaflags");
    rowhead.createCell((short) 8).setCellValue("cdrcost");


    String strQuery = "";
    ResultSet rs = null;

    conexion conexiondb = new conexion();
    conexiondb.Conectar();

    strQuery = "SELECT * FROM cdrcost where date(calldate) between '" + datum1 + "' and '" + datum2 + "'";

     //strQuery = "SELECT * FROM cdrcost where date(calldate) between '2011-09-01' and '2012-01-01'";

    rs = conexiondb.Consulta(strQuery);
    int i = 1;
    while (rs.next()) {
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) i);
        row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rs.getString("calldate"));
        row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs.getString("src"));
        row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(rs.getString("dst"));
        row.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(rs.getString("dstchannel"));
        row.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(rs.getString("lastapp"));
        row.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue(rs.getString("duration"));
        row.createCell((short) 6).setCellValue(rs.getString("disposition"));
        row.createCell((short) 7).setCellValue(rs.getString("amaflags"));
        row.createCell((short) 8).setCellValue(rs.getString("cdrcost"));
        i++;
    }
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    hwb.write(fileOut);     
    hwb.write(response.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");
    FileOut.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);

}

}
```

Comment: are you getting any exception or errors in the console?

Comment: @SajanChandran Sir i am not getting any save as dailogue box on clicking export button neither exporting is happening

Comment: check your server log files for any exceptions.